# jquery to display the dynamically generated textbox value in the samepage without using alter function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

1. Display the number of textbox based on user request.ex:If we type 4 in a textbox then 4 textbox will be generated in a same row.

2.If we press remove then that 4 box Should be removed.

3.Display the Dynamically generated textbox value in a same page

4.store these records in Database

I done coding for 1 option .Can anyone help me for other 3 options.

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Add / Remove Records</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div { padding:8px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table border="2" style= "background-color: lightblue;" >
        <thead>
            <h1 font style="color:blue">Add / Remove Records</h1>
        </thead>
        <thead>
            <tr> <th>Approval_No:</th>
                <td><input type="text" value=""/><br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>No. of Entries:</th>
                <td><input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="mytext1"><br/></td><br/>

            </tr><tr>
            <td> <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button></td>
            <td><button class="submit_button">Submit</button></td></tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields = 20; /*maximum input boxes allowed*/
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); /*Fields wrapper*/
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); /*Add button ID*/
        var sb = $(".submit_button");

        var x = 1; /*initlal text box count*/
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ /*on add input button click*/
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ /*max input box allowed*/
                x++;
                var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("mytext1").value);
                var b = document.getElementById("wrapper");


                $(wrapper).append('<div style="clear:both"></div>');
                for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                    var input = document.createElement("input");
                    $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="mytext"/>'); 
                    /*add input box*/
                }
                $(wrapper).append('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove_field">Remove</a><div style="clear:both"></div>');
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ /*user click on  remove text*/
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
        $(sb).click(function(e) {
            var message = document.getElementById("mytext1").value;
            dm.innerHTML= message;
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You repeat the same by taking each of these value of mytext[] and push it into an array and you can take value from the array

Answer (score 0):

- Group the textboxes created with a div and generate an id.. Set the
- delete button to have an attribute for referenc (data-group) give the
  inputs a class for easier access
- Get the data as an object. (You can transform as you wish)

Here's thejavascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; /*maximum input boxes allowed*/
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); /*Fields wrapper*/
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); /*Add button ID*/
  var sb = $(".submit_button");

  var x = 1; /*initlal text box count*/
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { /*on add input button click*/
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { /*max input box allowed*/
      x++;
      var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("mytext1").value);
      var b = document.getElementById("wrapper");

      /**Group the textboxes..**/
      var htmlElements = [];
      htmlElements.push('<div id="group_' + x + '">');
      htmlElements.push('<div style="clear:both"></div>');

      for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        htmlElements.push('<input type="text" name="mytext[]" class="more-fields" id="mytext_' + i + '"/>');
        /*add input box*/
      }
      htmlElements.push('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove_field" data-group="group_' + x + '">Remove</a>');
      htmlElements.push('<div style="clear:both"></div>');
      htmlElements.push('</div>'); /**End the textbox grouping..**/
      $(wrapper).append(htmlElements.join("")); /**End the textbox grouping..**/
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { /*user click on  remove text*/
    e.preventDefault();
    var group_id = $(this).data("group");
    $("#" + group_id).remove();
    x--;
  });
  $(sb).click(function(e) {
    var data = {};
    $(".more-fields").each(function(){
            data[(this.attr("id"))] = $(this).val();
    });

    //You now have the data as json.. (data)

    var message = document.getElementById("mytext1").value;
    //dm.innerHTML = message;
  });
});
```

See working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/popsyjunior/dzfmvgt1/

Cheers..!!

Comment: How can i store the textbox values to the database and display the stored value in html page..

Comment: The values are in a json format in the "data" variable. You can loop through and get the values. Also, if the answer satisfies your question, you should mark it as correct answer.

Comment: First Table structure like 'approval_no, titlesrno, tabletitle'. First row must store here. Each column to Each Row.
 Second Table structure like 'approval_no, titlesrno, recordsrno, tablerecords'. Remaining all rows must store here. Each Column to Each Row..